# Ethernet over USB

Tags: yocto

I am new to Yocto, playing with the `core-minimal-image` and trying to run it on my pocketbeagle. I would like to SSH into my pocketbeagle over the USB port. I know it is possible, as the default image provided for that board does exactly that.

I found a [pocketbeagle-meta](https://github.com/e-ale/meta-pocketbeagle) on github, and am using that to build. Looking at the kernel config, I see that it sets [a bunch of USB-related options](https://github.com/e-ale/meta-pocketbeagle/blob/master/recipes-kernel/linux/files/defconfig#L1678-L1683), i.e.:

```
CONFIG_USB_USBNET=m
CONFIG_USB_NET_AX8817X=m
CONFIG_USB_NET_AX88179_178A=m
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDCETHER=m
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_EEM=m
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_NCM=m
```

Flashing the default image and plugging it into my computer results in the board being powered, but my computer does not recognize any USB device (checking with `dmesg`, and nothing happens).

So I tried to load the `cdc_ether` kernel module, by adding:

```
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "cdc_ether"
```

to *core-image-minimal.bb*, but that does not change anything.

What am I missing for my pocketbeagle to be recognized as an ethernet device through USB?

Comment: Not sure why I got a -1... is that the wrong place to ask? Or is it a stupid question?

Comment: Take this to `StackOverflow`

Comment: @Shan-Desai its hard to distinguish here, as it could very well also be generic linux concepts of module loading to be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally learned that `cdc_ether` is for the host-side of the USB (here, the computer), and `g_ether` is for the gadget-side (here, the pocketbeagle). The pocketbeagle has an OTG USB, meaning that it can choose between host and gadget. But my computer is always a host, and therefore needs a gadget on the other side.

That's the reason why `cdc_ether` running on the pocketbeagle would not be recognized when plugging the board into my computer!

In the end, just starting `g_ether` (`modprobe g_ether`) is enough for the pocketbeagle to be recognized by my computer as a network interface.

Note: it turned out that the [OE/master branch of pocketbeagle-meta](https://github.com/e-ale/meta-pocketbeagle/tree/OE/master) was working better for me, already including `g_ether`!